# Change tab menu background colors

Tags: css, layer

How can I change the the tab header colors so initially all tab header has a dark layer on them, when I hover over them its layer changes to a bit lighter (greyish) and when a tab header selected, it is the brightest. Just like it does now with the text color, but I want to do that with the background colors.

CSS CODE:

```
.ing_div_in_appl label {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 -1px;
padding: 15px 25px;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
color: #c2c2c2;
border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.ing_div_in_appl label:hover {
  color: #888;
  background-color: blue !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ing_div_in_appl input:checked + label {
  color: #fff;
}
```

I was thinking maybe using `before` tag and add a dark layer there

```
.ing_div_in_appl label:before {
display: block;
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

I also Created a [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWXOOq).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this snippet :

```css
*:before,

*:after {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

  box-sizing: border-box;

}

html,

body {

  height: 100%;

}

body {

  color: #555;

  background: #eee;

}

p {

  margin: 0 0 20px;

  line-height: 1.5;

}

.ing_div_in_appl {

  min-width: 320px;

  max-width: 800px;

  padding: 50px;

  margin: 0 auto;

  background: #fff;

}

.ing_div_in_appl section {

  display: none;

  padding: 20px 0 0;

}

.ing_div_in_appl input {

  display: none;

}

.ing_div_in_appl label {

  display: inline-block;

  margin: 0 0 -1px;

  padding: 15px 25px;

  font-weight: 600;

  text-align: center;

  color: #fff;

  border: 1px solid transparent;

  background: #555;

}

.ing_div_in_appl label:hover {

  background-color: #aaa;

  cursor: pointer;

}

.ing_div_in_appl input:checked + label {

  color: #fff;

}

#ing-tab1:checked ~ #ing-content1,

#ing-tab2:checked ~ #ing-content2,

#ing-tab3:checked ~ #ing-content3,

#ing-tab4:checked ~ #ing-content4,

#ing-tab5:checked ~ #ing-content5 {

  display: block;

}

#ing-tab1:checked ~ label[for*='1'] {

  background-color: rgb(66, 180, 229)

}

#ing-tab2:checked ~ label[for*='2'] {

  background-color: #FF6214

}

#ing-tab3:checked ~ label[for*='3'] {

  background-color: #E18484

}

#ing-tab4:checked ~ label[for*='4'] {

  background-color: #C11D1D

}

#ing-tab5:checked ~ label[for*='5'] {

  background-color: #36AA61

}
```

```html
<div class="ing_div_in_appl">

  <input id="ing-tab1" type="radio" name="ing-tabs" checked>
  <label for="ing-tab1">TAB 1</label>

  <input id="ing-tab2" type="radio" name="ing-tabs">
  <label for="ing-tab2">TAB 2</label>

  <input id="ing-tab3" type="radio" name="ing-tabs">
  <label for="ing-tab3">TAB 3</label>

  <input id="ing-tab4" type="radio" name="ing-tabs">
  <label for="ing-tab4">TAB 4</label>

  <input id="ing-tab5" type="radio" name="ing-tabs">
  <label for="ing-tab5">TAB 5</label>

  <section id="ing-content1">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="ing-content2">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin
      turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump
      corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto
      pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="ing-content3">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="ing-content4">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin
      turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump
      corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto
      pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section id="ing-content5">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin
      turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump
      corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
  </section>

</div>
```

EDITED :

```
// Normal
#ing-tab1 ~ label[for*='1'] {
  background-color: rgb(66, 180, 229)
}

// Hovered
#ing-tab1 ~ label[for*='1']:hover {
  background-color: rgb(61, 155, 195);
}

// Checked
#ing-tab1:checked ~ label[for*='1'] {
  background-color: rgb(43, 111, 140)
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit unclear. I didn't mean to make the grey all the way, just have an overlay on them so the initial color the have had is just darker.

Comment: Check my edit. That is for the first tab. You have to set the other 3 colors for each of the remaining tabs

Comment: For some reason I cannot set the first tab's background color with the method you suggested. But there is no problem with the others tab. What did I miss? [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrENPa)

Comment: Remove the commented line `//`